# How to fix guzzlehttp truncated 500 internal server error codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want to make the web rest client use Guzzle but an error "500 internal server error" appears

i've tried using $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(); but nothing has changed

here is my controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('model_regis');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

}

public function index(){
    $username   = $this->input->post('namaDaftar');
    $email      = $this->input->post('emailDaftar');
    $nomor      = $this->input->post('nomorDaftar');
    $password   = $this->input->post('passwordDaftar');

    $this->model_regis->add($username,$email,$password,$nomor);

    redirect(base_url());
}



/*public function tambah(){
    $this->load->view('form_login');
}*/

public function guzzle_get($url,$uri){
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => $url]);
    $response = $client->request('POST',$uri);
    return $response->getBody()->getContents();
}
```

my model

```
public function __construct(){

    /*$this->_client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'http://malltik.com/malltik_api/user'
    ]);*/
}

public function add($username, $email, $password, $nomor){

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $data = array(
            'user_nama' => $username,
            'user_email' => $email,
            'user_pass' => $password,
            'user_number' => $nomor,
            );

        $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://malltik.com/malltik_api/user/registrasi', [
            'form_params' => $data
        ]);

        $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContent(), true);

        return $result;
    }
```

i want make a register function on rest api

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and searching across the internet, I have found a simple solution.

First, you have to catch the exception and then show its contents.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => $this->url]);
try {
    $response = $client->request('POST', '');
    return $response->getBody();
} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
    return $e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();
}
```

I hope this piece of code help you.